# create an array from javascript variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to push some values into an array but when i alert that array it shows me [object,object],[object,object],[object,object],[object,object]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(":button").click(function(event){
     var value = $('#box').val();
    if (value==""){
        return false;
        }
       else{$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=value",
        function(data){
            var array=[];
            $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
                var user=item.from_user;
                var created_at=item.created_at
                array.push({date:'created_at',username:'user'});
            });alert(array);
            });
        }
      });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a problem.

When you alert an object (which `{date:'created_at',username:'user'}` will create) it will be stringified to `"[object object]"`. (You can change that by overriding the `toString` function of the object).

The array does contain the objects.

(OK, technically there is a problem, but the symptoms you describe are unrelated to it, the values you are putting in to the objects are string literals and not variables, you shouldn't quote them).

Comment: you know how to loop this array of objects?

Comment: @user1526175 — The same way you loop any array. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Programming_-_the_real_basics#Loops

Answer (score 0):

First I spot a small bug in your code. When you create the object to push in the array you don't use the values but fixed strings (in upticks). You should alter that line to this version:

```
array.push({date:created_at, username:user});
```

If you try to visualize internal state (debugging information) then using `alert()` gives only a poor visual representation. Instead of `alert()` You could use `console.log()` instead.

This statement creates output in the console. Not every browser supports it. Internet Explorer has the developer tools. You can active them by simply pressing F12. But as far as I can see IE has very limited output. Firefox can be extended with the Firebug plugin (a very powerful tool!).

When you call `console.log(array)` in your code the output in Firebug shows something like this

```
[Object { date=..., username = ... }, Object { date = ..., username = ...}]
```

Since `console.log()` isn't supported by all browsers you should remove the calls before you release your sources in production.

Answer (score 0):

You are using strings instead of variables to create your object:

```
array.push({date:'created_at',username:'user'});
```

should be:

```
array.push({date:created_at,username:user});
```

or

```
array.push({date:item.created_at, username:item.from_user});
```

After creating the object, use `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging.  The default `Object.toString()` implementation, which gets called by alert, returns the `[object  Object]` you are seeing.

Comment: does anyone know how to loop this array of object or even to make your life easier recommend me a book that has all this.. cheers!!!!!